# Python import statement semantics

Tags: python, python-import

I'm having difficulty understanding the import statement and its variations.

Suppose I'm using the `lxml` module for scraping websites.

The following examples show...

```
from lxml.html import parse
parse( 'http://somesite' )
```

...Google's python style guide prefers the basic import statement, to preserve the namespaces.

I'd prefer to do that, but when I try this:

```
import lxml
lxml.html.parse( 'http://somesite' )
```

...then I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'html'

Can anyone help me understand what is going on?  I'd much prefer to use modules within their namespaces, but need some assistance understanding the semantics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import lxml.html as LH
doc = LH.parse('http://somesite')
```

`lxml.html` is a module. When you `import lxml`, the `html` module is not imported into the `lxml` namespace. This is a developer's decision. Some packages automatically import some modules, some don't. In this case, you have to do it yourself with `import lxml.html`.

`import lxml.html as LH` imports the `html` module and binds it to the name `LH` in the current module's namespace. So you can access the parse function with `LH.parse`.

---

If you want to delve deeper into when a package (like `lxml`) imports modules (like `lxml.html`) automatically, open a terminal and type

```
In [16]: import lxml

In [17]: lxml
Out[17]: <module 'lxml' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.pyc'>
```

Here is you see the path to the `lxml` package's `__init__.py` file.
If you look at the contents you find it is empty. So no submodules are imported. If you look in numpy's `__init__.py`, you see lots of code, amongst which is

```
import linalg
import fft
import polynomial
import random
import ctypeslib
import ma
```

These are all submodules which are imported into the `numpy` namespace. So from a user's perspective, `import numpy` automatically gives you access to `numpy.linalg`, `numpy.fft`, etc.

Comment: Should I think of lxml as a package, then?  Is there any consistent way to figure out what modules are automatically loaded into my program?

Comment: @TravisLelue: In Python a directory which contains an `__init__.py` is a package. Thus, `lxml` is a package. A module is any `.py` file inside a package. My edit (hopefully) explains how you can find out what modules automatically get imported into a package's namespace.

Comment: All submodules and subpackages in the directory structure will be available in their parent package's namespace once they've been imported, regardless of whether they're imported in the `__init__.py` for the package or not.  `__init__.py` only makes it so that anything `imported` therein is automatically available as soon as the package is imported, and through  the `from x.y import z` form used in `__init__.py` allows the developer to decouple the package directory hierarchy from the package namespace layout.

Answer (score 6):

Let's take an example of a package `pkg` with two module in it `a.py` and `b.py`:

```
--pkg
   |
   | -- a.py
   |
   | -- b.py
   |
   | -- __init__.py
```

in `__init__.py` you are importing `a.py` and **not** `b.py`:

> import a

So if you open your terminal and do:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> pkg.a
>>> pkg.b
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b'
```

As you can see because we have imported `a.py` in pkg's `__init__.py`, we was able to access it as an attribute of `pkg` but `b` is not there, so to access this later we should use:

```
>>> import pkg.b   # OR: from pkg import b
```

HTH,

Answer (score 3):

When you `import` a package, the interpreter looks up the package on the pythonpath, then if found, parses and runs the package's `__init__.py`, building a package object from it, and inserts that object in to `sys.modules`.  When `importing` a module, it does the same thing, except it creates and adds a module object.  When you subsequently attempt to access an attribute (aka a member method, class, submodule, or subpackage), it retrieves the corresponding object from `sys.modules` and attempts a `getattr` on the module or package object for the child you want.  However, if the child is a submodule or subpackage that has not yet been `imported`, it has not been added to `sys.modules` or the module or package's attribute list, so you get an `AttributeError`.  Thus, you have to explicitly import a module or package, either in your code, or delegated in a package's `__init__.py` for it to be available at runtime on its parent.